# Using Qt with LPGL license for a revenue generating, non-distributed private project

Tags: software, licensing, open-source-software, gpl

I am planning on porting my Python based TradingBot to C++ due to Python's GIL limitation. I have looked up a few c++ libraries like boost and Qt. I'm more inclined to use Qt because of its excellent documentation.

Can the Qt library be used with LGPL license? I'm not distributing the application to anyone; it's only used for personal purposes. Also the TradingBot will generate revenue.

Comment: Please provide a link to the library you want to use, and if available, also a link to its license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Qt library" you are talking about is the library available under [these licensing options](https://www1.qt.io/faq/#_Toc_1_2):

- Commercial
- LGPLv3
- GPLv2
- GPLv3

then the the answer is: Yes

The Qt library can be used with LGPLv3 license.

When a software library is available with multiple licensing options, the downstream recipient can *choose* the license that fits the project best.

> I'm not distributing the application to anyone; it's only used for personal purposes.

Actually, if that is the case, you don't need to worry.

None of the three different FLOSS licenses for the Qt library restricts *use*. They regulate *distribution* of derivative works.  If you're not going to distribute anything, you can do pretty much whatever you like under these licenses (including mixing ARR-stuff into the combo).

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for not linking the library. What's ARR?

Comment: ARR = All Rights Reserved (i.e. a proprietary library)